# What does Arrow function do: ECMAScript 6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Here is an example:

```
onChange = (event, { newValue }) => {
    this.setState({
      value: newValue
    });
};
```

Is this any different from

```
onChange(e, {newValue}) {
  this.setState({
     value: newValue
  });
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: check the use of arrow function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: *What does arrow function do* It does what the documentation says it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is:

```
onChange = (event, { newValue }) => {
    this.setState({
      value: newValue
    });
};
```

will retrieve `this` from the outer scope of the function, so it would refer to the `this` of the place where it was defined at.

```
onChange(e, {newValue}) {
  this.setState({
     value: newValue
  });
}
```

On this, `this` will refer to the `this` that the function is called with, so `this` would not refer to the `this` from where it was called from but from the object it is binded to.

For more information check [Arrow Functions (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: Please close duplicates as duplicates instead of answering.

Comment: @torazaburo I do not have enough reputation to close questions and thought it would be more useful to give an actual answer instead of leaving the other incomplete and confusing answer as the only one.

Comment: From https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions: *If you don't have enough reputation to cast close votes, or have used up your close votes for the day, there are alternatives: If the question is a duplicate, post a comment with a link to the original.*

Comment: @torazaburo Then what would you like me to do? Delete my answer? I just did my job of answering questions I can answer and not leaving wrong/unclear answers such as the below one. I know I'm wrong but I think it's also wrong leaving the other answer to this question here as the sole answer for those who won't follow the link to the original question.

Comment: Just a note for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

The arrow function version binds to the `this` context - probably what you want for an event callback.